# Working around AntiForgeryToken to post form data

Tags: wpf, post, webbrowser-control, antiforgerytoken

I am currently writing a website that will eventually be used as a stand-along application.  As a result, I created an MVC application and handle the login through a form.  It then redirects to another page which is essentially all the user will see for a while.  Until the rest of the application is completed, this entire website will be viewed by the users within a WPF application's WebBrowser control as part of that application.

Since the user must log in to the WPF application, I would like to keep them from having to log in twice.  So, my WPF application has code to navigate to the login url and post the data as follows:

```
Uri linkUri = new Uri("https://www.myURL.com/Account/Login");
ASCIIEncoding encode = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] postData = encode.GetBytes("grant_type=password&username=" + _user.UserName + "&password=" + _user.Password);
string postHeaders = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
this.myWebBrowser.Navigate(linkUri, null, postData, postHeaders);
```

Based on Fiddler, I think I am sending the data correctly.  However, when the WebBrowser displays, it shows the error page with

> The required anti-forgery cookie
>   "__RequestVerificationToken_L1NjaGVkdWxlci5XZWI1" is not present.

Since I never load the initial page with the AntiForgeryToken, this is expected.  However, I was wondering if there were a way around this issue.  For example, is there a way to silently load the form and post it without the user seeing it?  Or, am I stuck just removing the AntiForgeryToken for now until the site is no longer used within WPF?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Use OAuth to authenticate users from the third party site.